# Does thread synchronization mean thread safety?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

Thread synchronization or serialization, strictly defined, is the application of particular mechanisms to ensure that two concurrently-executing threads or processes do not execute specific portions of a program at the same time. (From wikipedia).

So if an object implements thread synchronization, does it mean that it's thread safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread synchronization is a method for achieving thread safety.  Thread safety just means that a program can run multiple threads at the same time without any chance of the threads corrupting each other's state.

It's possible to have thread safety without thread synchronization in some cases, though -- for example, if two threads both read from the same data structure but no thread ever modifies the data structure, that program can be thread safe without any thread synchronization required.  There are also some lockless data structures that are designed to be useable by multiple threads without synchronization.

> So if an object implements thread synchronization, does it mean that
>   [it has] thread safety?

If the synchronization was done correctly, yes.  It's very easy to do it incorrectly (or incompletely) if you're not careful, in which case even with the synchronization the program might still occasionally crash or give incorrect output due to lack of thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Thread synchronization means Thread safety. If 2 tickets are there and 3 customers are there. Then, if I have to declare a method for randomly choosing which threads will get the tickets must be a a synchronized method.Please take a look at this example which is very easy to understand.

```
        public class ThreadSynchronization {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Ticketbooking tb = new Ticketbooking();
                Thread t1 = new Thread(tb);
                Thread t2 = new Thread(tb);
                Thread t3 = new Thread(tb);
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
                t3.start();
            }

        }

        class Ticketbooking implements Runnable {
            int tickets = 3;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("waiting => " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                m1();

            }

            private synchronized void m1() {
                if (tickets > 0) {
                    System.out.println("booking for => " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    tickets--;
                    System.out.println("Booked for => " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    System.out.println("tickets now => " + tickets);

                } // if
                else {
                    System.out.println("ticket not booked for => " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                } // else

            }
        }// end1 
    /*
    The output will be :
    waiting => Thread-0
    waiting => Thread-1
    waiting => Thread-2
    booking for => Thread-0
    Booked for => Thread-0
    tickets now => 1
    booking for => Thread-2
    Booked for => Thread-2
    tickets now => 0
    ticket not booked for => Thread-1
*/
```

This can also be solved using Executors.newFixedThreadPool().Here is the solution :

```
public class Test13 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ticketbooking1 tb1 = new Ticketbooking1();

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            service.execute(tb1);
        }
        service.shutdown();

    }
}

class Ticketbooking1 implements Runnable {
    int tickets = 2;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("waiting => " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        m1();

    }

    private synchronized void m1() {
        if (tickets > 0) {
            System.out.println("booking for => " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tickets--;
            System.out.println("Booked for => " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("tickets now => " + tickets);

        } // if
        else {
            System.out.println("ticket not booked for => " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } // else
    }

}// end1

/*  The output :
 * waiting => pool-1-thread-1
waiting => pool-1-thread-3
waiting => pool-1-thread-2
booking for => pool-1-thread-1
Booked for => pool-1-thread-1
tickets now => 1
booking for => pool-1-thread-2
Booked for => pool-1-thread-2
tickets now => 0
ticket not booked for => pool-1-thread-3

 */
```

Synchronization is not required if we use Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(). Here I have not made method m1 as synchronized .

```
public class Test13 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ticketbooking1 tb1 = new Ticketbooking1();

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        service.execute(tb1);
        service.execute(tb1);
        service.execute(tb1);
        service.shutdown();

    }
}

class Ticketbooking1 implements Runnable {
    int tickets = 2;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("waiting => " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        m1();

    }

    private void m1() {
        if (tickets > 0) {
            System.out.println("booking for => " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tickets--;
            System.out.println("Booked for => " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("tickets now => " + tickets);

        } // if
        else {
            System.out.println("ticket not booked for => " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } // else
    }

}// end1

/*  the output :
 * waiting => pool-1-thread-1
booking for => pool-1-thread-1
Booked for => pool-1-thread-1
tickets now => 1
waiting => pool-1-thread-1
booking for => pool-1-thread-1
Booked for => pool-1-thread-1
tickets now => 0
waiting => pool-1-thread-1
ticket not booked for => pool-1-thread-1

 * 
 * 
 * */
```